# Design a datastructure for telephone directory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Design a datastructure for telephone directory for storing the name and phone number so that we can search for key given name and vice versa.

We can use 2 hash maps as follows

```
Map<String,int>
Map<int,String>
```

But it requires twice the memory.Can anyone suggest any other solution?

Comment: it will not require twice the memory, assuming your strings are larger then 2, because the map holds (or can hold) only a reference to the string, and NOT the actual string, so you will be able to store the string only once, and just have 2 pointers to it, which is not too bad.

Comment: the phone number should also be a `string`. If it's a homework then better add a tag.

Comment: @NickDandoulakis Yes! Phone numbers are _not_ numbers!

Comment: "twice" means "constant" (memory complexity), which is not that bad for your requirement (to *doubly* map). I can't recommend you a better (data structure...without ruining the run time)!

Answer (score 1):

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a
>   map that preserves the uniqueness of
>   its values as well as that of its
>   keys. This constraint enables bimaps
>   to support an "inverse view", which is
>   another bimap containing the same
>   entries as this bimap but with
>   reversed keys and values.

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

```
BiMap<String, Integer> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

biMap.put("Mike", 123);
biMap.put("John", 456);
biMap.put("Steven", 789);

BiMap<Integer, String> invertedBiMap = biMap.inverse();
```

**Edit:** [Multimaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
multimap.put("John", "111111111");
multimap.put("John", "222222222");
multimap.put("Mike", "333333333");

System.out.println(multimap.get("John")); //[222222222, 111111111]

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : multimap.entries()){
    if(entry.getValue().equals("222222222")){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()); //John
    }
}
//or

Multimap<String, String> inverted = HashMultimap.create();
Multimaps.invertFrom(multimap, inverted);
System.out.println(inverted.get("222222222")); //[John]
```

Answer (score 1):

One person can have more than one number, and one number can belong to more than one person (members of a family). And as Nick said, a telephone number in general case can have non-numeric characters. All considered, instead of `Map<String,int>` you might be using `Map<String,List<String>>`, or to have only pointers to strings (in C++ terms), to avoid redundancy: `Map<String*,List<String*>>`.

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is storing the Strings in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and have a '$' sign indicate the end of each string. use doubly linked pointers for each step, and hold a double linked pointer from each '$' (end of name) to its number (in an array or a list).

now, when you want to get a phone from name:

```
find the '$' indicating the end of the word for this string.
it is connected to a number in a list - that is your number.
```

when you want to get a name from a phone:

```
find the number, it is connected to a '$' sign.
follow the up-links all the way to the root, this will get you the name (reversed). 
reverse it and you are done.
```

also, as I said in the comment (regarding the double map approach): assuming your strings are pretty large, and the map holds a pointer/reference to the string (and not the actual string), you can assume the storage space needed will not be double, but something much better.

Answer (score -1):

Using a binary search tree for implementing the telephone directory is the best way to do it. Think about the practical implementation of the mobile phone telephone contact list. It is sorted alphabetically. If one uses map template then we shall not get a sorted list. You can not sort the elements of the map, and it's not effective.

The only way to do it is the binary tree way. Since, while adding a new entry it's inserted in a ordered way. So, no more sorting is needed. It's already ordered. Remember, left_tree < root, and root < right_tree in case of binary tree.

Comment: maps are implemented (not be definition but by convention) as RB-trees. Perhaps you were confused with unordered_map (a.k.a. hashtables)?